# Fixed point of a function defined in terms of a metric on a compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, and assume $f : X → X$ satisfies
$$d(f(x), f(y))< d(x, y), \forall x \neq y ∈ X.$$
Define a function $g : X → \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = d(x,f(x)), \forall x ∈ X$. Prove the following statements.

a) $|g(x)-g(y)| \leq 2d(x,y), \forall x,y \in X$.

b) $g$ is continuous and $g(x)=0$ for some $x \in X$.

$\text{Proof:}$

a) Observe that
\begin{align*}|g(x)-g(y)| 
&=|d(x,f(x))-d(y,f(y))| \\
&=|d(x,f(x))-d(f(x),y)+d(f(x),y)-d(y,f(y))| \\
&\leq |d(x,f(x)-d(f(x),y)|+|d(f(x),y)-d(y,f(y))| \\
&\leq d(x,y)+d(f(x),f(y)) \\
&\leq 2d(x,y),
\end{align*}
whre in the last step we used the hypothesis that $d(f(x), f(y))< d(x, y), \forall x \neq y ∈ X.$

b) To show continuity we take $\delta= \large\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then if $d(x,y)< \delta$, we have by part a) that $|g(x)-g(y)|< \varepsilon$.

To show that there exists $x\in X$ such that $g(x)=0$, we follow AlexL's answer and note that since $g$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, $g$ attains its minimum at some $x \in X$. Suppose that for that for $g(x)\neq 0$, and so $f(x)\neq x$. Then
$$g(f(x))=d(f(x),f(f(x)))<d(x,f(x))=g(x),$$
which is a contraction to $g$ attaining its minimum at $x$. It follows that $g(x)=0$, and this completes the proof.

Comment: You have a small error. In the statement of a) an in the last displayed line of he proof of a) the inequality  $<$ should be $\leq$ to include the case $x=y.$  It would be easier to make this change than to re-write it to cover only the case $x\ne y$.

Comment: Another way to prove that $g$ is continuous: It suffices that if $ \lim_{n\to \infty}d(x,y_n)=0$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}|g(x)-g(y_n)|=0.$  Use your proof of a),  writing $y_n$ for $y.$ Then  $|g(x)-g(y_n)| \leq 2d(x,y_n)$..... So if $d(x,y_n)\to 0$ then $|g(x)-g(y_n)|\to 0 .$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is compact and $g$ continuous, there exists $x_0 \in X$ such that $g(x_0)$ is minimal. I let you show that we must have $g(x_0)=0$.